# Finding reCaptcha ID with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Alright, so I've been trying to pull the reCaptcha ID out of a web source that I'm downloading, I was going to do this with Regex, pull the line out with what it contains it, then pull the ID from there [If that makes sense].

Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
        WebClient W = new WebClient();
        W.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string pattern = "recaptcha_challenge_field";
        string SourceCode = W.DownloadString("http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?COLLCC=4025385947&COLLCC=1765882190&site=1132330052");

        foreach (string Match in Regex.Split(SourceCode, Environment.NewLine))
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(Match, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Match);
            }
        }
```

Problem being, that it just shows the whole page source besides the line with the "pattern" in it. I tried changing the encoding type because I thought it was returning the source as one big sentence, but I guess that's not the answer. Any help here guys? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you have terrible name convention!
Local variable should have names starts with small letter, so "sourceCode", "match". Big letter suggest that "Match" is class not variable.

Secondly, why you using Split from Regex class only to split string by new lines? Use build-in string method:

```
foreach (string line in sourceCode.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
```

Now... if you notice, I change the name of variable, so now your code will looks like

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

And you will see obvious, code do excaly what you want: If line match the pattern, then show whole line.

Another thing: what is your regex pattern? This is more like comparison to check if it's match or not. Try read about regex more. Your pattern should looks more like 
`recaptcha_challenge_field=([0-9]+)`. I don't know exactly, because the link you are posted contain only "refresh" meta tag.

And try to use [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) method instead Regex.IsMatch. It gives you more information, not only if the string match your pattern, but what groups within you capture.

Comment: It still returns the whole source for me though. What about for you?

Comment: It's returns nothing for me, because I don't known what you are looking for. The page are blank, or full of html but the field don't have any value. Did you change code to use `Regex.Match`? And did you change the pattern to use some capturing groups? If so, you should not get hole line. FYI: if you create proper pattern you will not have to split the line in fist place. But first try single line at the time, this is simpler to learn how to produce good regex

Comment: Just try to set the pattern to "<a" or something like that, and set the request for Google, it will still return the whole source.